# Use local images in Internet Explorer control for windows phone

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, windows-phone, online-game

I'm planning to create a game for `Windows Phone`. To make it simpler to port it, I want it to be `HTML`-based and as it's an online game, it get's the `html` pages via `http`. But to minimize the data use, I want all the images in the game to be in the phones storage. So how can I create a website displayed in the `Internet Explorer` control that uses local images?

Comment: Would HTML localStorage be an option to store the base64 encoded images? Mobile IE10 does support it.

Comment: So you mean writing the images into the local storage via javascript and reading them out? I'd prefer the user to download the images together with the app, but I'd be happy to see an example code as answer anyway.